# UpdateProgress Control Remains Visible on Safari and Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I am using the ASP.NET Ajax controls UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress. The idea of a the UpdateProgress control is to display a message while the page is performing a partial postback, then disappear when the postback completes. On Firefox and Internet Explorer, this happens correctly. However, on Safari and Chrome the UpdateProgress control remains visible after the postback completes. Is this a bug in the ASP.NET Ajax Framework, or is there another workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be it? http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/10/20/Gotcha-WebKit-(Safari-3-and-Google-Chrome)-Bug-with-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx

Comment: This fixed the problem. It looks like the problem was originally solved here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1252014/2392110.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in other way by setting up properly ASP.NET 2.0 browser support - just by putting a per-browser config to your app. For more information see here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/manipulating-aspnet-20-browser-support/569

For BB config is here: 
[http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800878/800733/How_To_-*Configure*.NET_2.0_for_BlackBerry_Browser_support?nodeid=1365369&vernum=0](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800878/800733/How_To_-_Configure_.NET_2.0_for_BlackBerry_Browser_support?nodeid=1365369&vernum=0)